# Join types of Netezza

Tags: join, netezza

I am having trouble getting an official list of join types in Netezza/PureData.

According to a powerpoint presentation I read, there are 5 types:

1. Hash Join: Requires equi-conditions, identical types. Fastest
2. Exist Join: A type of Hash Join?
3. Expression Join: Also called Nested Loop joins?
4. Merge Joins: Are they merge sort joins? Some articles mention that are like Hash Joins but for floats
5. Cross Product Join: Slow?

And as you can see, I have a lot of gaps of knowledge. Unfortunately, I have yet to find a comprehensive documentation that covers this topic. Any input on this will be appreciated.

Comment: can those IBM users make up their own tag? #puredata is already taken.

Comment: @MaxN you can always edit the Q and remove the offending tag (which i just did); of course this does not solve the underlying problem

Comment: I hope you guys know that most of us Netezza users associate the term "PureData" with Netezza because the connection between the terms were officially made explicit (ala http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/puredata/analytics/). We take no part in your little battle over the "right" to use that name. Down-voting constructive posts and labelling them as "offending" your tag is childish and unbecoming of professional developers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's my swag at an answer. I think the best way to think about it is to consider how the join is expressed in SQL, and then consider the join algorithm that is used by the database to resolve them under the covers.

---

**Equi-join**

Joins of this form, where the join criteria is an equality comparison, and each term is a simple column reference (i.e. not an expression).

```
SELECT ...
FROM tableA a
   JOIN tableB b
   ON a.col1 = b.col
```

*Algorithms*

Netezza will most often resolve Equi-joins using a **Hash Join** approach where the hashed value of the join columns can be compared to verify equality.

In certain circumstances, Netezza may use a **Merge Sort Join** approach in cases where the data being joined is already sorted (e.g. using Materialized Views) making this normally expensive approach more attractive, or when the data types being compared are such that a hash comparison is not reliable (e.g. floating point data types).

---

**Expression Joins**

Joins of this form, where the join criteria is anything but an equality comparison.

```
SELECT ...
FROM tableA a
   JOIN tableB b
   ON a.col1 < b.col
```

*Algorithms*

Since a simple equality evaluation isn't sufficient, Netezza handles these cases with a **Nested Loop** approach. Each row in tableA is evaluated individually against each row in tableB.  It is for this reason that expression join can never be a co-located join in Netezza. The Nested Loop approach is therefore quite expensive.

---

**Cross Joins**

Joins of this form, where there the join criteria does not include any columns from at least one of the table.

```
SELECT ...
FROM tableA a
   JOIN tableB b
   ON a.col1 = 0
```

or
    SELECT ...
    FROM tableA a,
       tableB b

*Algorithms*

Netezza will take cartesion product approach to resolving these, which can be quite expensive, and also cannot be a co-located join as every row in every data slices must be joined to every row in every other data slice.

---

**Implict IN/EXISTS Joins**

Statements such as these are not explicitly joins in SQL, but may be processed as joins by the database.

```
SELECT ...
FROM tableA a
WHERE col1 IN
   (
      SELECT col1
      FROM tableB
   )
```

or

```
SELECT ...
FROM tableA a
WHERE NOT EXISTS
   (
      SELECT *
      FROM tableB b
      WHERE a.col1 = b.col1
   )
```

*Algorithms*

Netezza will approach these statements with an **Exists Join** approach, which is fundamentally the same as the Hash Join approach, but since no joined data is required in the result set, it only has to tally existence in the process.

Comment: Are IS NULL and IS NOT NULL also treated as equi-join?

Comment: These expressions test of a value (or the lack of a value), but don't compare columns themselves.  They can be added to an equi-join without disrupting the equi-join, but are processed as a restriction node in the plan file.

Comment: That's most informative. Thanks. Out of curiosity, are you from IBM Netezza?

Comment: I do, but now I think I'm obligated to say that anything posted here is my personal opinion and doesn't necessarily represent IBM's opinion, etc.  :)

Comment: Damn, I was about to ask you to sign it :). Guess I will have to ask Natasha Y for confirmation.

Comment: There is literally nothing I could say that she couldn't improve upon!

Comment: Off-topic: Is she your boss?

Comment: By the way, I asked an IBM Netezza staff member to vet this post. One critique she has is that the second EXPRESSION JOIN with the "ON a.col1 + 10 = b.col -3" is actually a HASH JOIN. And ofc, I still find this post to be very valuable because the way you express the information is much easier for us to absorb and you cite very good examples.

Comment: Ah, you are/she is quite right. It would be a hash join or merge sort join, it just couldn't be a coached join. I had my head too wrapped up in the collocation topic and it seeped in here. I'll remove that!

Comment: She's not my boss, just my hero.

Comment: Make that "couldn't be a colocated join". Thanks, autocorrect.

Comment: Thanks, I am also on the verge of confusing colocation with HASH JOINs. haha